# app not visible on all devices on google play

Tags: codenameone

I have made an app with [codename one](http://www.codenameone.com)

Now, I have put the app on google play. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.n10k.UltimateGRE

Everything is working fine.

However, the app is not searchable from the **play store app** installed on (Samsung)Galaxy Tab

Its searchable from other phones but not from the TAB.

Google says that it won't show the app in search results on some devices if the app is not compatible on that device.

Is codename one app not compatible with Galaxy tab? Is this some resolution issue? How do i ensure that my app is searchable from EVERY android device?

Answer (score 0):

When submitting an app to Google play you get a dialog indicating the limitations imposed on the application the content of that dialog would help in verifying why an application doesn't appear for a specific device.

Keep in mind the market takes time to refresh so its possible the application will appear.

As far as I know there is no limitation and all apps should work on all devices.